# How apt-get install some certain version of CMake?

Tags: 12.04, apt, cmake

How can I install some certain version of CMake via apt-get install ?

Is there any limitation in ubuntu 12.04 about CMake version?

Answer (score 1):

The latest `cmake` version for Precice (12.04) is `cmake (2.8.7-0ubuntu4)`.
And no, usually you can't install different `cmake` versions via the package manager at the same time.